# SQL select inside select using a datetime column as reference

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, where-clause

I have a table that looks like the one below:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id_object ║ Name    ║ Activity    ║ Object_Prefix ║ Start_DateTime      ║ End_DateTime        ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 213       ║ Junior  ║ Fixing      ║ G35           ║ 06-11-2020 09:35:06 ║ 06-11-2020 16:39:34 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 213       ║ Junior  ║ End_turn    ║               ║ 06-11-2020 17:01:25 ║                     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 213       ║ Richard ║ Auxiliating ║ G35           ║ 06-11-2020 09:35:06 ║ 06-11-2020 16:39:34 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 213       ║ Richard ║ End_turn    ║               ║ 06-11-2020 17:04:07 ║                     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 456       ║ Philip  ║ Fixing      ║ G08           ║ 02-11-2020 13:35:09 ║ 02:11:2020 21:58:59 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 456       ║ Philip  ║ End_turn    ║               ║ 02-11-2020 22:37:51 ║                     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 102       ║ Julia   ║ Auxiliating ║ N901          ║ 31-10-2020 20:01:30 ║ 01-11-2020 08:09:41 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 102       ║ Julia   ║ End_turn    ║               ║ 01-11-2020 08:13:45 ║                     ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I've been trying to select the End turn Times as a new column, although so far what i tried with no success was:

```
 select  
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.activity,
  DATE_FORMAT( t1.Start_DateTime, "%d/%m-%Y %H:%i:%s") as Start,
  (Select DATE_FORMAT(t1.Start_DateTime, "%d/%m-%Y %H:%i:%s")
    from Activities t2 
     WHERE t2.Activities = "End_turn" AND t2.id_object = t1.id_object) as end_activity
  FROM 
   Activities t1 
 WHERE 
 t1.Object_Prefix != ""
GROUP BY
t.Start_DateTime
```

The result i was expecting was something like this:
[image: ExpecteResult]

but the column end_turn is always coming filled with null values. I didnt figured it out where i missing it.

Comment: Please show us the results that you want.

Comment: could you please check my edited question and please let me know if it still missing information..

Comment: Why is your subquery returning `t1.Start_DateTime` instead of `t2.Start_DateTime`?

Comment: May I know are your `Start_DateTime` and `End_DateTime` columns data type is `datetime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. there are inconsistencies between your example data and your query.

```
select  
  t1.id, <--- there is no column named as `id`. Instead it was `id_object`
  t1.name,
  t1.activity,
  DATE_FORMAT( t1.Start_DateTime, "%d/%m-%Y %H:%i:%s") as Start,
  (Select DATE_FORMAT(t1.Start_DateTime, "%d/%m-%Y %H:%i:%s")
    from Activities t2 
     WHERE t2.Activities = "End_turn" <---- there is no column named as `activities`. Instead it was `activity`.
   AND t2.id_object = t1.id_object) as end_activity
  FROM 
   Activities t1 
 WHERE 
 t1.Object_Prefix != ""
GROUP BY
t1.Start_DateTime
```

2. I've tried your query with the example data you've given and I got:

> Error Code: 1242
> Subquery returns more than 1 row

3. The `GROUP BY` is on the `t1.Start_DateTime` column doesn't make sense since it seem to clearly show in your expected results that you want them to group them by `id_product` and `name`.
4. Your date format in `Start_DateTime` and `End_DateTime` columns is `dd-mm-yyyy` whereas the standard MySQL date for date related data type is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Lastly, if the Start_DateTime and End_DateTime columns data type is date/datetime, I suggest this query:

```
SELECT id_object, `Name`, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Activity ORDER BY Start_DateTime ASC),',',1) ac, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Object_Prefix <> '' THEN Object_Prefix END) op,
       MIN(CASE WHEN activity <> 'End_turn' THEN Start_DateTime END) sdt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'End_turn' THEN Start_DateTime END) edt
FROM activities
GROUP BY id_object, `Name`;
```

And you can see the demo here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=de2af89c39e6636cfb45ee179cfb1461

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to bring the `start_datetime` of the "end turn" row for the same `id_object` and `name`. In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        min(case when activity = 'End_turn' then start_datetime end)
            over(partition by id_object, name) as end_turn
    from mytable t
) t
where activity <> 'End_turn'
```

In earlier versions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select min(t1.start_datetime)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id_object = t.id_object and t1.name = t.name and t1.activity = 'End_turn'
    ) as end_turn
from mytable t
where activity <> 'End_turn'
```